# Botões da notificação Android não aparecem no dispositivo móvel

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Sempre interagi com a minha aplicação Android pelo emulador, mas recentemente comecei a testar tudo o que fiz com o meu telemóvel.

Criei algumas notificações com botões, e no emulador elas aparecem como esperado e fazem o que é suposto, porém no meu telemóvel, só a notificação é que aparece os botões não existem.

Alguém me sabe dizer o porquê de isto acontecer?

Deixo aqui parte do código onde crio os botões na notificação.

```
Intent intentCriado = new Intent(context, CriadoService.class);
intentCriado.putExtra("id", id);
intentCriado.putExtra("idTrabalho", idTrab);

PendingIntent resultPendingTrablalhoCriado =
        PendingIntent.getService(context,
                0,
                intentCriado,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );

Intent intentCancelado = new Intent(context, CanceladoService.class);
intentCancelado.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
intentCancelado.putExtra("idTrabalho", String.valueOf(idTrab));

PendingIntent resultPendingTrablalhoCancelado =
        PendingIntent.getService(context,
                0,
                intentCancelado,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("TRABALHOS:")
        .setContentText(mensagem)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingTrablalhoCriado)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Sim", resultPendingTrablalhoCriado);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Não", resultPendingTrablalhoCancelado);
mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

Comment: Quais  as versões do Android do emulador e do telefone?

Comment: Do telemóvel 5.1.1 do emulador 7.1.1 @ramaral

Comment: Se de facto a versão do telemóvel é 5.1.1 não vejo razão para isso acontecer, a não ser que a notificação precise de ser expandida manualmente.

Comment: testei com um emulador que tem a mesma versão que o meu telemovel 5.1.1, e realmente os botoes da notificação não aparecem, mas no emulador com versão 7.1.1 aparecem.... @ramaral

Comment: Verifique se consegue expandir a notificação com os dedos.

Comment: eu deslizo o dedo para baixo e aparece uma imagem bastante distorcida e reparei que os dois botoes estão lá, mas não ficam claros...  @ramaral